# A thing of the past

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I'm looking for the right word to describe a thing of the past that no longer needed nor it is useful, but we still have it in our world today. 
Example:
- vaccines for illnesses that are gone for really long time (SO that vaccine is the thing of the past. I'm not saying it is true, just trying to give an example)
- or an old thermometer which was replaced with other better devices but its still exists.
- or a paper business card that no longer in use as much (lets assume that everybody knows how to store information digitally)

Thanks a lot!
Anna

Comment: Can you give more context? Are these things that would be kept in a museum? Are they simply hanging around gathering dust because they haven't been thrown out? Why are these things still around and where are they being kept?

Comment: All of those things are still useful. Well, maybe a thermometer in the [Réaumur scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9aumur_scale), not so much.

Comment: Do you mean *obsolete* (or one of its many synonyms)?

Comment: This is the usual meaning of the word *antique*. But that word is so common that I'm not sure asking about it is on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective '**anachronistic**' or the noun '**anachronism**' -- something "out of time", used for something old-fashioned that is still extant.

Answer (score 0):

How about antiquated" (old-fashioned or outdated)?